# symfony The file was found but the class was not in it

Tags: php, symfony

when I run this command on my terminal

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:validate
```

I get this error

```
  The autoloader expected class "tuto\testBundle\Entity\product" to be defined in file "../src/tuto/testBundle/Entity/product.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or names  
  pace probably has a typo.
```

I using symfony 2.8 and my code like the example page so what's the wrong ?

the product.php file code

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 */
class product 
{


  /** 
  *@ORM\Column(type="integer")
  *@ORM\Id
  *@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")  
  */


  private $id;
  /** @ORM\Column(length=140) */




  public function getUserId(){
    return $this->UserId;
  }
  public function setUserId($id){
    return $this->UserId=$id;
  }
}
```

and the product.orm.yml file

```
AppBundle\Entity\product:
  type: entity
  table: product
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to capitalize your class name:

```
class Product
```

See symfony coding standards [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/code/standards.html). Specifically, [PSR-1](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/) specifies using StudlyCaps for class names.